# Trouble in set the date in windows xp only after 8/2008

Tags: windows, windows-xp, date, control-panel

I'm having trouble setting the date in Windows XP.

**Specifications:**

- Microsoft windows xp professional 2002
- Service Pack 2
- Intel Pentium 4 CPU 2.90 GHz
- RAM 512 MB

---

Every time I try change my date to the current date, and after pressing the Apply or OK, it automatically returns to date 08/08/2008.

In addition, when I change the date to before the month of August 2008 it successfully changes, even after reboot and the separation of electricity, changing the date to after 1/8/2008, it changes back automatically to 08/08/2008.

I confirmed the prerogative of the user, and the validity of BIOS battery. This problem has not appeared in the same copy of Windows on other devices.

What is the cause of the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: Have you scanned your computer for virus or malware?

Comment: I installed Windows newly after completely format the hard drive ..

Comment: Has your BIOS battery dried out? Did you protect your BIOS with a password. What motherboard model is inside your computer?

Comment: I do not think the BIOS battery problem ...
Because when I changed the date to before 2008 and cut off electricity to the device, has been saved successfully Date when it runs again !!

Comment: @DoktoroReichard motherboard model: P4VM800 
and non password for bios ..

Comment: "Cutting off electricity" doesn't confirm a bad BIOS battery.

Comment: As @moses said, you need to replace your Battery with a new one to check whether it died or not. Checking the manual at the [ASRock page](http://www.asrock.com/mb/VIA/P4VM800/?cat=Manual) the motherboard is at least from April 2005 (slightly older than mine :P). Since this is 2013, maybe the battery died at a time where your clock was set to 08/08/2008. It probably is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do:

1- Try this: Turn on you PC. Enter BIOS, and change the time in there (To something like 10/11/2013 5:28 AM, anything but 8/8/2008), then save BIOS (usually by pressing F10, but it differs on different systems), and immediately after the start-up process of you computer , (before it tries to load your operating system), turn your system off. Wait for half an hour or more, then turn on your computer and directly go to BIOS. If the time and date is back to 08/08/2008, then there is something wrong with the mentioned battery of you BIOS.

2- If you are sure that the battery is OK, you should check your operating system for any suspecious applications. You can try many free malware scanners out there, like Sophos, Malwarebytes Anti-Malware, Housecall free scanner, AVG AntiVirus, and a lot more.

3- There might be some scheduled tasks running on your system (some might play such pranks) reverting your system's time. To see if such tasks are the cause you can either go to Control Panel>>Scheduled Tasks, or you could use command prompt and type in "schtasks" and see if there are any unwanted tasks that automatically run on your system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've change BIOS battery, 
And i installed Windows recently after completely reformat the hard drive, And confirmed there is no of Scheduled Tasks, ... 

But the same problem still appears :(